# Django and MySQL -- the data is different between the two

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I have a Django app that uses MySQL as a backend. I'm having difficulties where the raw MySQL records show one value, but Django presents something else in the web app.

For example, I have a table for client data. One of the fields in each record is called `snailMailInvoice` and is a Y/N choice -- default is Y (`varchar` type).

```
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| snailMailInvoice  | varchar(3)   | NO   |     | Y       |                |
```

The raw MySQL:

```
select * from systems_system_contact where lastName="SomeClient";
...a bunch of other fields... | snailMailInvoice |
...a bunch of other fields... | N
```

Then, in the Django App, the form displays `Y` (the other choice). It is like the Django App can't see the MySQL value, so it defaults to `Y`. If, through the Django App, I select `N` and save the form, THEN the value sticks to `N` in Django.

Why would this be happening?

**EDIT** - to add some code

Forms.py:

```
class System_Contact_Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = System_Contact
        exclude = ('isMainContact', 'systemOwner', 'companyName', 'isRessyContact')
```

Views.py:

```
def contact_details(request, scID):
    redirect_to = request.REQUEST.get('next', '/systems/contacts/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        syscontEdit = System_Contact.objects.get(pk=scID)
        form = System_Contact_Form(request.POST, instance=syscontEdit)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
    else:
        syscontView = System_Contact.objects.get(pk=scID)
        form = System_Contact_Form(instance=syscontView)

    c = {
        'form':form,
        'cancel':redirect_to
        }

    return render_to_response('pages/systems/contact_details.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Models.py:

```
class System_Contact(models.Model):
IS_MAIN_CONTACT_CHOICES = (
    ('Y', 'Yes'),
    ('N', 'No'),
)

IS_SYSTEM_OWNER_CHOICES = (
    ('Y', 'Yes'),
    ('N', 'No'),
)

IS_RESSY_CONTACT_CHOICES = (
    ('Y', 'Yes'),
    ('N', 'No, this is a commercial contact'),
)

TRADE_CHOICES = (
    ('EL', 'Electrician'),
    ('LA', 'Landscaper'),
    ('PL', 'Plumber'),
    ('TR', 'Trencher'),
)

SNAIL_MAIL_CHOICES = (
    ('Y', 'Yes'),
    ('N', 'No'),
)

SNAIL_MAIL_INVOICE_CHOICES = (
    ('Y', 'Yes'),
    ('N', 'No'),
)


firstInitial = models.CharField(max_length = 10, verbose_name = 'First Initial', blank = True, null = True)
firstName = models.CharField(max_length = 60, verbose_name = 'First Name', blank = True, null = True)
lastName = models.CharField(max_length = 160, verbose_name = 'Last Name', blank = True, null = True)
phonetically = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = 'Phonetically', blank = True, null = True)
companyName = models.CharField (max_length = 160, verbose_name = 'Company Name', blank = True, null = True) #Only used for Commercial Owners, no other field needed
homePhone = models.CharField(max_length = 60, verbose_name = 'Home Phone Number', blank = True, null = True)
officePhone = models.CharField(max_length = 60, verbose_name = 'Office Phone Number', blank = True, null = True)
cellPhone = models.CharField(max_length = 60, verbose_name = 'Cell Phone Number', blank = True, null = True)
faxNumber = models.CharField (max_length= 60, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name = 'Fax Number')
isMainContact = models.CharField (max_length = 3, verbose_name = 'Is the Main Contact?', choices = IS_MAIN_CONTACT_CHOICES, default='N')
isRessyContact = models.CharField (max_length = 3, verbose_name = 'Is this a Ressy Contact?', choices = IS_RESSY_CONTACT_CHOICES, default='Y')
isArchived = models.BooleanField(verbose_name = 'Archived?', default = False)
systemOwner = models.CharField (max_length = 3, verbose_name = 'Is a System Owner?', choices = IS_SYSTEM_OWNER_CHOICES, default='N')  #this is just a flag to say they own a system
worksFor = models.CharField (max_length = 70, verbose_name = 'Works For', blank = True, null = True)
tradeType = models.ForeignKey(Contact_Trade, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Trade')
emailAddress = models.EmailField(verbose_name = 'Email Address', blank = True, null = True)

billingAddress = models.CharField(max_length = 150, verbose_name = 'Billing Address', blank=True, null=True )
billingCity = models.CharField(max_length = 90, verbose_name = 'Billing City', blank=True, null=True)
billingProvince = models.CharField(max_length = 30, verbose_name = 'Billing Province', blank=True, null=True)
billingPostalCode = models.CharField(max_length = 10, verbose_name = 'Billing Postal Code', blank=True, null=True)
snailMailOnly = models.CharField(max_length = 3, verbose_name = 'Snail Mail Only?', choices = SNAIL_MAIL_CHOICES, default='Y')
snailMailInvoice = models.CharField(max_length = 3, verbose_name = 'Snail Mail Invoice?', choices = SNAIL_MAIL_INVOICE_CHOICES, default='Y')
```

Comment: Can you provide some of the code in the `views.py` where you call the form? And the respective `forms.py`?

Comment: the easiest way to debug is to print the sql statement generated by your queryset and run it manually against the database and see what it returns.

Comment: @akonsu -- I did that and found that the database shows the correct value, but the querie run in the `shell` shows a value of `u'N\r'` -- whatever that is. I'm guessing that there is an issue with how my data is being imported?? (I'm moving data out of an Excel file by saving as a CSV, then importing the data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK -- I figured it out.

I realised there was something connected with the fact that in my CSV file, the `snailMailInvoice` field is the LAST field on each line. Thus, at the end of the line there is a carriage return. I assumed that this was a `\n` -- thus in my MySQL command to import the CSV, I state `terminated by '\n'`.

However, the MySQL picked up a '\r' on EVERY line and was adding it to the `snailMailInvoice` field. Thus, every record has either a `Y` or a `N` with a `\r` attached.

I amended my MySQL import statement to have: `lines terminated with '\r\n'` Now everything is working as expected.

Lesson learned.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: your fields that can be either Y or N can easily be implemented as BooleanField's in which case you would have caught your error much earlier.

Comment: Indeed -- These are models that were implemented when I was first learning Django. I'm in the process of cleaning up a LOT of models/data. Thanks.